# difficulty about passing function returning functor or monad type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, functor

I run into a case that monad on return type hinders the high-order function  programming.

```
val fOpt: (x: Int) => Option[Int]

def g(f: Int=>Int): Int
```

How do I call `g(fOpt)` and get result as `Option[Int]` ?
My solution is `Try(g(fOpt(_).get)).toOption`. but I'm not satisfied.

Is there methods that I don't know can solve this. I ask this because I know less about functional programming (so many pattern and theory).
I expect there would be something like `functor` for function return such that it can work like `val ret:Option[Int] = fOpt.mapReturn(f=>g(f))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily implement the syntax that you proposed (I called it `toAmbient` instead of `mapReturn`, and later I replaced `f` by `h` to make the separation of the identifiers more obivous).

Here is an implementation that uses an implicit wrapper class on functions:

```
implicit class UnsafeEmbedAmbientOps[X, Y](f: X => Option[Y]) {
  class NoneToAmbientEmbeddingException extends RuntimeException
  def toAmbient[Z](a: (X => Y) => Z): Option[Z] = {
    try {
      Some(a(f(_).getOrElse(throw new NoneToAmbientEmbeddingException)))
    } catch {
      case e: NoneToAmbientEmbeddingException => None
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can define `f: Int => Option[Int]` and various `g, g2` that take `Int => Int` and return `Int`:

```
val f: Int => Option[Int] = x => Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 9).get(x)
def g(f: Int => Int): Int = f(1) + f(2)
def g2(f: Int => Int): Int = f(1) + f(42)
```

and then pass `f` to `g` and `g2` as follows:

```
println(f.toAmbient(h => g(h)))
println(f.toAmbient(h => g2(h)))
```

This will print:

```
Some(5)
None
```

---

**Extended comment**

I want to try to explain why I find `Try(g(fOpt(_).get)).toOption` actually *good*.

Suppose that there were some natural way to transform every

```
f: X => Option[Y]
```

into an

```
fPrime: X => Y
```

This would imply that there is a natural way to transform every `Unit => Option[Y]` into an `Unit => Y`. Since `Unit => Y` is essentially the same as `Y`, this would in turn imply that there is some way to transform every `Option[Y]` into an `Y`. But there is no natural transformation from `Option[Y]` to `Y`. This is a rather general phenomenon: while there is `point`/`unit`, and it is always easy to get into the monad from `X` to `M[X]`, there is generally no safe/easy/lossless way to get *out* of a monad from `M[X]` to `X`, e.g.:

- Calling `get` on `Option[X]` returns `X`, but can throw `NoSuchElementException`
- Likewise, calling `head` on `List` can throw exceptions, and also throws away the `tail`.
- Awaiting a `Future` is blocking
- Sampling an `X` from a random `Distribution[X]` leaves you with a fixed `X`, but erases information about probabilities of all the other possible `X`

etc.

The fact that you can work around the type signature `g(f: Int => Int)` with `Try` is because the `Int => Int` part is not really precise: it is not the identity monad, but rather the default ambient monad that supports state and exceptions. In "reality", `g` is rather something like `g(f: Int => DefaultAmbientMonad[Int])`, because `f` can also throw exceptions.

Now, the interesting thing is that while there is no guaranteed way to get from `Option[X]` to `X`, there actually *is* a way to get from `Option[X]` to `DefaultAmbientMonad[X]`: just throw some very special `NoneEmbeddingException` if the `Option` is `None`. Getting from `DefaultAmbientMonad` to `Option` is again unsafe: you can catch your special `NoneEmbeddingException`, but then you have to "pray" that no other exceptions will be thrown (that's why it is "unsafe").

So, the most "systematic" way to pass `fOpt` to `g` would actually be

```
class NoneEmbeddingException extends RuntimeException

try {
  Option(g(fOpt(_).getOrElse(throw new NoneEmbeddingException)))
} catch {
  case e: NoneEmbeddingException => None
}
```

This is what I've implemented in the code snippet above.

But this is almost what you have already with `Try(...).toOption`, except that you use the predefined `NoSuchElementException` instead of the somewhat contrived `NoneEmbeddingException`!

So, I would just say: your solution is correct, it can be justified by a systematic discussion of the natural transformations from the `Option` monad to the default ambient monad, and it is not particularly astonishing. My personal opinion: just use `Try(...).toOption`, it's ok.

Comment: is ambient monad just an identity monad?

Comment: @WeiChingLin That's exactly the point: it isn't! By default, all your code executes with funny side effects, affects the state of the memory on the heap, and it can throw exceptions. That's as far from the pure-function-composition-identity-monad as it can possibly get. That's why you can "embed" `Option` in this ambient non-formalized "monad" by throwing exceptions and then catching them.

Comment: Hi @AndreyTyukin - I was trying to understand your solution and it looks to me that even though function g and g2 expects a function Int => Int the function f can return a None which can only be caught at run time and not during compilation. Is that correct understanding ? Also, X=>Y=>Z for my understanding is truly Int => Option[Int] => Option[Int] even though in the implicit class it is represented as Int => Int => Int, is that correct?

Comment: @jjayadeep The construction is such that `f` *should* occasionally return a `None`, and the `getOrElse` *should* occasionally throw an exception. This is intended. We have deliberately replaced the explicit declaration of return type `Option[Y]` by the vague `Y`, under which we mean: it could return an `Y`, but it *could* also have side effects, or it *could* throw exceptions. That's indended. We are dropping the explicit `Option`, and from then on work in the sloppy ambient monad. As I tried to explain that  `(X => Y) => Z` is "truly" `(X => AmbientMonad[Y]) => AmbientMonad[Z])`, [... t.b.c]

Comment: @jjayadeep [...continued...] ... except that the `AmbientMonad` is nowhere formalized, and is never shown in function signatures. The `(X => Y)` part is *supposed* to throw. The whole `(X => Y) => Z` is also *supposed* to throw exceptions. It's just that the `AmbientMonad` is never written out explicitly, so instead of writing `(X => AmbientMonad[Y]) => AmbientMonad[Z]` we have to resort to `(X => Y) => Z`, which looks deceiptively similar to identity monad, but is indeed very far away from the identity monad, because it has exceptions and side-effects.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTyukin. I will look up Monads... to understand them better :). One final question h=> g(h) is equal to g(map.getFunction) is that correct?. If that is the case why the compiler is not able to check the types to see that g is expecting a function Int=>Int but map.getFunction is of type Int =>Option[Int] ?

Comment: @jjayadeep [...continued...] The problem is: the whole monad-formalisms in Scala only make sense as long as the programmers decide to keep their code sufficiently pure. But in reality, nothing in the type system holds you back from throwing exceptions and mutating state, even if you are not explicitly working in `StateT[...]` or `Try[...]`. Therefore, you can "hide" exceptions and side-effects (and also `Option`) in the ambient monad. That's exactly what we have done here: we have hidden `Option` in the ambient monad. ; On your follow-up question: I'm not sure what `map` and `getFunction` is?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin the map and getFunction is : x => Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 9).get(x) so I think the complier should catch that g(h) is actually g(Int=>Option[Int]) and not g(Int=>Int)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167950/discussion-between-andrey-tyukin-and-jjayadeep).